How to Open a Div in a Dialog Without Interrupting Data Flow in Angular with Material?
I have an Angular application using Angular Material, and I want to open a div element in a dialog when I click a button. Additionally, I need to ensure that the data flow within the div remains uninterrupted.
Here's what I have so far:

In my app component, I have a div that logs a timer using RxJS. This is to ensure the data flow continues even when the dialog is open.
I used @ViewChild to capture the element and pass it to the dialog.

However, my approach doesn't seem to work. I want the div to move into the dialog when the button is clicked and return to the original template when the dialog is closed, all without breaking the data flow.
Here's my example code:
import '@angular/localize/init';
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  importProvidersFrom,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { VERSION as CDK_VERSION } from '@angular/cdk';
import {
  VERSION as MAT_VERSION,
  MatNativeDateModule,
} from '@angular/material/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Dialog } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';

/* eslint-disable no-console */
console.info('Angular CDK version', CDK_VERSION.full);
console.info('Angular Material version', MAT_VERSION.full);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  in app
  
  <div #foo>{{now | async | json}}</div>

  <button (click)="openDialog()">open dialog</button>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('foo') foo: any;

  dialog = inject(Dialog);

  now = timer(0, 5 * 1000);

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.foo);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule),
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));

Stackblitz demo
What is the correct way to achieve this behavior in Angular with Material?

You can pass the data as a second argument to open function.
Then ng-template autobinds the data into data property of the template which you can access directly.
Angular Material Documentation Reference
import '@angular/localize/init';
import {
  Component,
  ViewChild,
  importProvidersFrom,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { VERSION as CDK_VERSION } from '@angular/cdk';
import {
  VERSION as MAT_VERSION,
  MatNativeDateModule,
} from '@angular/material/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Dialog } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';

/* eslint-disable no-console */
console.info('Angular CDK version', CDK_VERSION.full);
console.info('Angular Material version', MAT_VERSION.full);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  in app
  <ng-template #foo let-data>
  <div>{{data.now | async | json}}</div>
</ng-template>

  <button (click)="openDialog()">open dialog</button>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('foo') foo: any;

  dialog = inject(Dialog);

  now = timer(0, 5 * 1000);

  openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(this.foo, {
      data: {
        now: this.now,
      },
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule),
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));

Stackblitz Demo

From the MatDialog open() API, it only supports the first argument value which is the ComponentType<T> or TemplateRef<T> type.
You need to wrap your <div> into the <ng-template> element.
<ng-template #foo [ngIf]="true">
  <div>{{now | async | json}}</div>
</ng-template>

import {
  TemplateRef
} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('foo') foo!: TemplateRef<HTMLDivElement>;

Besides, work with shareReplay() RxJS operator to replay value between the subscribers.
import { shareReplay, timer } from 'rxjs';

now = timer(0, 5 * 1000)
  .pipe(shareReplay(2));

Demo @ StackBlitz

shareReplay will solve the example app because I'll have the same stream. but what if I have something else? I want to render something in the component template and when I click on the button to "cut" it to the dialog and it still works with all the binding.

1st question You use timer RxJS just to demonstrate the data update right? 2nd question, in your dialog, are you updating any value? If yes, it seems like your (new) requirement in the comment is not specified in the question. If not, you can see in my demo that when closing the dialog, it is still updating the value.
